# Handling errors from ArcGIS Feature Service applyEdits operation

Tags: arcgis-server, feature-service, server-object-extension

When users calls applyEdits on our FeatureService, and get's something wrong with the request - it just returns "unable to complete operation".

Is it possible, to somehow get the detailed error?

I know that detailed errors are logged in ArcGIS logs.
I want to see those errors and return them to the client.

I can build SOI that could handle those requests, that go to the applyedits, that would be the preferable place to handle this. (We are using ArcGIS server 10.6.1)

Option that states "build your own SOE that does what applyedits does" is not acceptable, unless it is "easy" to build.

We had our own save operations made from times, when there were no applyedits. To increase the performance and usability, we are migrating our applications to use FeatureService applyedits.

Specific reason - why - we are having some DB triggers, that does some validation. And they throw detailed exceptions. (These work also, when user use ArcMap - so they are important).

Feature service just returns "Unable to complete operation"....

I also asked this question in [Esri community forum](https://community.esri.com/message/934160-can-i-handle-service-errors-myself-within-soi).